# How to Send Emojis using RestTemplate in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate, spring-rest

My requirement is to send JSON data from service (A) to another service (B), in this case, I am sending emojis in JSON using Spring Boot RestTemplate. If I send a request from A to B, in the service B the message is displayed as a text with a question mark(?) instead of emoji.

Sending this JSON data

```
{
"from": "1233222225",
"to":  "8585855858",
"message": "Hello A, hope you are doing 23012020 "
}
```

displays in service B as

```
{
"from": "1233222225",
"to":  "8585855858",
"message": "Hello A, hope you are doing 23012020 ?"
}
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Where / How is the emoji entered into the applicatoin? Is it test data? Is it a web formular? There can be so many places where encoding is broken. Usually JSON should be encoded in UTF-8. So it should be capable to transfer emojis.

Comment: I am sending Json using  restapi .In logs, Emoji showing fine but when I sent same Json to another service getting the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this solution. it is working for me

while sending json data make sure that content type should be "application/json;charset=UTF-8" in headers. default it will take "application/json".

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to send emojis in encoded as below:

```
String ballEmoji = "\u26BD";
```

or you can use below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
    <artifactId>emoji-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>

EmojiParser.parseToUnicode(":smiley: some text");
```